# Mysql - Exclude where count > value but showing all rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, having

I have a table called customer_numbers like this:

```
ID   customer      number

1    1             10001
2    2             10002
3    2             10003
4    3             10004
5    3             10005
6    3             10006
7    3             10007
```

I want a query that produces the following result. I.E. excludes only those customers who have only one number.

```
ID   customer      number

2    2             10002
3    2             10003
4    3             10004
5    3             10005
6    3             10006
7    3             10007
```

I tried queries like this:

```
SELECT ID,customer,number from customer_numbers GROUP BY number HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Adding the GROUP BY clause lists all the numbers but the count(*) is always 1. Not having the clause means all the numbers are not listed, just a single result.

What would be the correct query?

Comment: Try to add customer to the group by along with just number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the `customer` only

```
select * from customer_numbers
where customer in(SELECT customer from customer_numbers GROUP BY customer HAVING count(*)>1)
```